# How can I resize a UIImageView in navigationItem.titleView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, ios11

I am attempting to resize the image that I placed in the `navigationItem.titleView` of my TableViewController.  I used the following code in my TableViewController `viewDidLoad` to accomplish this:

```
UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
[iv setImage:image];
self.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
```

However, the image does not seem to be affected by the frame of 40 x 40 that I set.  The result looks like this:

[image: navigation bar with large logo]

The image is clearly exceeding the 40 x 40 limit that I specified. **How can I get the image to not take up all the available space in the navigation bar?**  I want the logo to be smaller and have a bit of padding on the top and bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an `UIView`, add your logo on it and after that set `self.navigationItem.titleView` with this view. You can check my code below.

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];

UIImageView *titleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:titleView.frame];
titleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];;
titleImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[titleView addSubview:titleImageView];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```